# How to use information from a file in c

Tags: c

So we are trying to create a calculation for comparing ratings of movies given to us by users. We have separated this into different teams for our class project. I have been tasked with creating the calculation that reads from the file output from a different team and then creates an output using the calculation I come up with. Reading from the file is fine however I have not been able to figure out how to use that information for calculation.

This is my problem area:

```
    long int similarity;
#define MAXLINESIZE 80
FILE* myTextFile;
char ch;
char lineBuf[MAXLINESIZE] = { '\0' };
char *person [10] = { '\0' };
char *movie [10] = { '\0' };
char *rating [10] = { '\0' };


myTextFile = fopen("C:\\users\\owner\\desktop\\movieRating.txt", "r");

if(myTextFile == NULL){
    printf("Failed");
}


fgets (lineBuf, MAXLINESIZE - 1, myTextFile);

while ( !feof (myTextFile) && !ferror (myTextFile) ) {
    sscanf ( lineBuf, "%s %s %s", person, movie, rating);
    printf("\n person = %s \n movie = %s \n rating = %s \n", person,movie,rating);
    fgets (lineBuf, MAXLINESIZE - 1, myTextFile);

}
long int per = atoi(person[10]);
long int mov = atoi(movie[10]);
long int rat = atoi(rating[10]);
{
similarity = (per + rat) * (per + rat);
return (similarity);
printf("\n Similarity is %i\n", similarity);
getchar ();
}

getchar();
getchar ();
return 0;

}
```

Hopefully I have explained this right

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If your *problem area* is here:**

```
char *person [10] = { '\0' };
char *movie [10] = { '\0' };
char *rating [10] = { '\0' };
```

It should be changed to this:

```
char person [10] = { '\0' };
char movie [10] = { '\0' };
char rating [10] = { '\0' };
```

You want an array of characters.  Not an array of pointers.

**If your problem area is here:**

```
long int per = atoi(person[10]);
long int mov = atoi(movie[10]);
long int rat = atoi(rating[10]);
```

It should be changed to this:

```
long int per = atoi(person);
long int mov = atoi(movie);
long int rat = atoi(rating);
```

`person` is (now) an array of characters - which is what `atoi` expects.

`person[10]` is (now) a single character, illegally read from past-the-end of your array.

**If your problem area is here:**

```
return (similarity);
printf("\n Similarity is %i\n", similarity);
```

It should be changed to this:

```
printf("\n Similarity is %i\n", similarity);
return (similarity);
```

No further code in a function is executed after a `return`.

Comment: I though the main problem was `char *rating [10] = { '\0' };`. Using array of pointers to store chars.

Comment: Really nice of you to bother with such a question.

Comment: Thank you for helping a Newbie such as I. I have a working program now.